# How does this sequence continue?

Tags: pattern

Help me find the pattern in the sequence below:

3M1 0J3 3J1 1A3

Which three alphanumeric characters come next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next, I think, is

> 3S0, followed by 1O3.

These are

> months of the year. The letter in the middle is the first letter of the name. The digits are the number of days. For no obvious reason it appears that the digits alternate between being reversed and not being reversed. (Am I missing some clever reason for this?)

The sequence posted begins

> with May, perhaps just to be slightly less easy to spot.

Comment: Correct! I thought about starting in February to make things harder but I did not want to worry about leap year issues